# C++ atribuição de método

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Aluno{
    public:
    string nome;
    int idade;
    float n1;
    float n2;
    float media(float n1, float n2);
};

float Aluno::media(float n1, float n2){
    return (n1+n2)/2;
}

int main(){
    Aluno *aluno1;
    Aluno *aluno2;
    aluno1 = new Aluno();
    aluno2 = new Aluno();
    float media1, media2;

    aluno1->nome = "Igor";
    aluno1->idade = 19;
    aluno1->n1 = 3.0;
    aluno1->n2 = 4.5;

    aluno2->nome = "Walter";
    aluno2->idade = 19;
    aluno2->n1 = 5.5;
    aluno2->n2 = 2.5;

    media1 = aluno1->media(float n1, float n2);
    media2 = aluno2->media(float n1, float n2);

    cout << "Aluno: " << aluno1->nome << endl;
    cout << "Idade: " << aluno1->idade << endl;
    cout << "Média: " << media1 << endl;

    cout << "Aluno: " << aluno2->nome << endl;
    cout << "Idade: " << aluno2->idade << endl;
    cout << "Média: " << media2 << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Exatamente neste trecho:

```
media1 = aluno1->media(float n1, float n2);
media2 = aluno2->media(float n1, float n2);
```

Está ocorrendo o seguinte erro: `"expected primary-expression before float"`

Answer (score 1):

Tem um erro no seu código:

```
media1 = aluno1->media(float n1, float n2);
media2 = aluno2->media(float n1, float n2);
```

Você não precisa declarar o tipo antes de usar a função.

Troque para:

```
class Aluno{
    public:
    string nome;
    int idade;
    float n1;
    float n2;
    float media();
};

float Aluno::media(){
    return (n1+n2)/2;
}
```

Você pode usar as propriedades do objeto Aluno para fazer o cálculo da média.

```
media1 = aluno1->media();
media2 = aluno2->media();
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você faz:

```
media1 = aluno1->media(float n1, float n2);
media2 = aluno2->media(float n1, float n2);
```

Você está fazendo duas coisas incompatíveis, você está usando uma atribuição, e uma definição de método. O correto seria você definir o método média na classe aluno, como você realmente fez, e no método main apenas chamar esse métodos passando os parâmetros:

```
media1 = aluno1->media(n1, n2);
media2 = aluno2->media(n1, n2);
```